# How to select a column's value, only if all other entries with the same value exist and match? (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

The title is a bit messy, but here's an example
suppose we have table:

```
| name   | room |  
=================
| John   | 4    |  
| John   | 6    |    
| John   | 9    |  
| Smith  | 4    |  
| Smith  | 6    |  
| Brian  | 4    |  
| Brian  | 6    |  
| Brian  | 9    |
```

I want to select John and Brian because they both have exactly rooms 4, 6 and 9, but not Smith, since he doesn't have the room 9. (If we had another person who ONLY has room 4 and 6, then it'd select that other person as well as Smith).

I know I need to do some kind of correlated query, but I'm not sure how to actually get it to do something like

```
for a check for b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want groups of names that share the exact same rooms, I would recommend `group_concat()`:

```
select rooms, group_concat(name) as names
from (select name, group_concat(room order by room) as rooms
      from t
      group by name
     ) n
group by rooms;
```

If you want only combinations with more than one name, then add `having count(*) > 1` to the outer `select`.

Comment: would it be possible to return the names as separate values per row?I'm assuming I just have to remove one of the group_concats?

Comment: yup! removing one of the group bys got me the desired results. Thank you!

Comment: @Conanap  for next time, consider adding desire output. That help a lot bulding an answer